# Prove that the variance of the Generalized Least squares estimator is less than the variance of the OLS estimator

Tags: self-study, least-squares, generalized-least-squares, minimum-variance

Suppose, we consider the following regression model, $$Y = X\beta + \varepsilon$$ where $\varepsilon$ ~ $N(0, \sigma^2V)$ and V is a known $n\times n$ non-singular, positive definite square matrix.

Now **OLS estimator** of $\beta$ is $\tilde \beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y$ whereas, the **GLS estimator** of $\beta$ is $\hat \beta = (X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}X'V^{-1}Y$.

Then I need to show that the variance of **GLS** estimator $V(\hat \beta)$ is smaller than the variance of **OLS** estimator $V(\tilde \beta)$.
I was able to find that $V(\hat \beta) = \sigma^2(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}$ and $V(\tilde \beta) = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}X'VX(X'X)^{-1}$

So, I am trying to show that,
\begin{align}
V(\hat \beta) - V(\tilde \beta) 
& = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}X'VX(X'X)^{-1} - \sigma^2(X'V^{-1}X)^{-1}
\end{align}
this difference is a positive definite matrix. That's where I am stuck. I have no idea how to do that. Can anybody help??

please note that I know that in this case, the GLS estimator is BLUE (Best Linear Unbiased Estimator) according to Gauss-Markov Theorem. So It has the minimum variance. But I need to prove this particular case directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496112/how-to-prove-positive-semi-definitness-in-matrix-notation-without-numbers/496131#496131

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristophHanck